# TableViewDatasource and delegate not called when tableview is inside collectionview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios8.3

I have placed a uitableview inside collectionviewcell and have coded as below in the collectionviewcell class.But the datasource and delegate methods are not being called can any help me out to fix the issue

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {

        arrayMenuAlerts=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Suri",@"John",@"Phillip",@"Sachin", nil];
        [self.contentView addSubview:tableView];
        tableView.dataSource=self;
        tableView.delegate=self;
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)awakeFromNib {

    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    tableView.dataSource=self;
    tableView.delegate=self;
}
```

Comment: have you set datasource and delegate method of collectionview ?

Comment: `tableView` is an IBOutlet?

Comment: yes tableview is an ib outlet and i have set datasource ,delegate for collection view.Tableview is coming inside collectionview cell.But no data is returned from data source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because on the init Method the object "self" is not created yet. you can put tableView dataSource and Delegate in another method. like i did.

```
@synthesize tableview;
NSMutableArray *arrayMenuAlerts;

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    arrayMenuAlerts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Suri",@"John",@"Phillip",@"Sachin", nil];
    tableview.dataSource = self;
    tableview.delegate = self;
    [tableview reloadData];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    return [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [arrayMenuAlerts count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = arrayMenuAlerts[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```