# TableView within TableviewCell not displaying cells

Tags: swift, tableview, datasource, uitableview

I have a UITablaView inside  UITableviewCell. Here is my code:

UITableViewCell:

```
class ProductViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var totalOrderButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var productImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var productNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var productSubNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var productBioLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var mlButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var productQuantity: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var plusButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var minusButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var greenHeartButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var liquorsTableView: UITableView!

var fourLiquorStores: [LiquorStore] = []

var currentUser: User!

var currentProduct: Product! {
    didSet {
        updateUI()
    }
}

func updateUI() {
    downloadProductImage()
    productNameLabel.text = currentProduct.name
    productSubNameLabel.text = currentProduct.subName
    productBioLabel.text = currentProduct.description
    productQuantity.text = "\(currentProduct.quantity)"
    updateGreenHeart()

}
var cache = SAMCache.shared()
weak var delegate: ProductViewCellDelegate!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    liquorsTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 65
    liquorsTableView.rowHeight =  65
    liquorsTableView.delegate = self
    liquorsTableView.dataSource = self
    fetchLiquorStores()
}

func fetchLiquorStores() {
      LiquorStore.observeNewLiquorStore { (liquorStore) in
        LiquorStore.observeNewLiquorStore { (liquorStore) in
            if !self.fourLiquorStores.contains(liquorStore) {
                self.fourLiquorStores.append(liquorStore)
                self.delegate.updateTableView()
                print(self.fourLiquorStores)
            }
        }
    }
}




func downloadProductImage() {
    let productuid = currentProduct.uid
    let profileImageKey = "\(productuid)"

    if let image = cache?.object(forKey: profileImageKey) as? UIImage {
        productImage.image = image
    } else {
    currentProduct.downloadPopularProductImage { [weak self] (image, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            self?.productImage.image = image
            self?.cache?.setObject(image, forKey: profileImageKey)
        }
    }
    }
}


// Ad o delete Quantities
@IBAction func plusDidTap() {
    if currentProduct.quantity >= 1 && currentProduct.quantity <= 60 {
        currentProduct.quantity += 1
        delegate.updateTableView()

    }
}

@IBAction func minusDidTap() {
    if currentProduct.quantity > 1 {
        currentProduct.quantity -= 1
        delegate.updateTableView()
    }
}


func updateGreenHeart() {
    if let currentUser = currentUser {
        if currentUser.favoriteProducts.contains(currentProduct) {
            greenHeartButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "GreenHeartFilled"), for: [])
        } else {
            greenHeartButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "GreenHeart"), for: [])
        }
    }
}

// Ad or delete Favorite Products
@IBAction func greenHeartDidTap() {
    if currentUser.favoriteProducts.contains(currentProduct) {
        self.greenHeartButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "GreenHeart"), for: [])
        self.currentUser.deleteFavoriteProduct(product: currentProduct)
    } else {
        self.greenHeartButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "GreenHeartFilled"), for: [])
        self.currentUser.addFavoriteProduct(product: currentProduct)

    }
}
```

}

```
extension ProductViewCell: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return fourLiquorStores.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = liquorsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LiquorStoreViewCell", for: indexPath) as! LiquorStoresViewCell
    cell.currentProduct = self.currentProduct
    cell.liquorStore = self.fourLiquorStores[indexPath.section]

    return cell
}
```

}

UITablViewCell -2 :

```
class LiquorStoresViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var liquorStoreNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var liquorStorePriceLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var liquorStoreTimeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var starStackView: UIStackView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageViewBoard: UIImageView!

var currentProduct: Product!
var currentPriceIndex: Int = 0

var liquorStore: LiquorStore! {
    didSet {
        updateUI()
    }
}



func updateUI() {
changeLiquorStoreProductsUid()
liquorStoreNameLabel.text = liquorStore.userName
let index = liquorStore.products.index(of: currentProduct)
    if let index = index {
        let productPrice = liquorStore.products[index].price[currentPriceIndex]
       format(price: productPrice)
    }
}



// Format Product Price to Currency
func format(price: Double)  {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale.current // Change this to another locale if you want to force a specific locale, otherwise this is redundant as the current locale is the default already
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    if let formattedTipAmount = formatter.string(from: price as NSNumber) {
        liquorStorePriceLabel.text = "Tip Amount: \(formattedTipAmount)"
    }
}

// Func to organize LiquorStores
func changeLiquorStoreProductsUid () {
    for product in liquorStore.products {
        if self.currentProduct.name == product.name && self.currentProduct.description == product.description && self.currentProduct.subName == product.subName {
            let index = liquorStore.products.index(of: product)
            if let index = index {
                liquorStore.products[index].uid = currentProduct.uid
            }
        }
    }
}



override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    liquorStorePriceLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    liquorStoreNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    liquorStoreTimeLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    imageViewBoard.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.5239839702, green: 0.5239839702, blue: 0.5239839702, alpha: 1)
    for view in starStackView.subviews {
        let image = view as! UIImageView
        image.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "WhiteStar")
    }

}
```

}

The UITableView inside the UITableviewCell doesn't show the data :/
What's the problem?

This is what I'm building:
[StoryBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1nSt.png)

An this appears in the simulator, as you can see, the second tableview is empty:

[Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T5qn.png)

PD: I'm downloading successfully the liquorStores from firebase.

Comment: Is there a screenshot? I don't see one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586716/tableviewdatasource-and-delegate-not-called-when-tableview-is-inside-collectionv

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TableViewDatasource and delegate not called when tableview is inside collectionview cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586716/tableviewdatasource-and-delegate-not-called-when-tableview-is-inside-collectionv)

Comment: I  putted the screenshot in the link "StoryBoard" and "Simulator"

Comment: I _love_ how the liquor store array is called `fourLiquorStores`. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's *possible* to do what you are trying to do, it would be *much* simpler to rethink your architecture entirely. If your view controller displays only a single product, plus a list of liquor stores, then the product view shouldn't really be in a cell at all--just make it an ordinary view, and make that view your table's header. The cells will then be the liquor stores, and you no longer have to deal with nesting a table within a cell. Alternately, you *can* keep the product view in a cell, but just add prototypes for the liquor stores as a second kind of cell *in the same table*.

EDIT: Now that you've posted your storyboard screenshot, the easiest thing for you to do is to move your liquor store prototype cell up to the top-level table, remove the subtable from the top-level cell, and in your data source, have

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath path: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if path.row == 0 {
        return tableView.dequeueCellWithIdentifier("productDetailsCell")!
    } else {
        return tableView.dequeueCellWithIdentifier("liquorStoreCell")!
    }
}
```

Comment: Great!! That's what I need, Thank you so much!!

Comment: Glad it helped!